# CSS3 keyframe animation not working in firefox and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css, firefox, css-animations

My css code works in chrome and safari but not on Firefox, IE and Opera.
when i create @keyframes rotate {} , for other browsers, this not worked
is that for this 4 line:
    `animation-duration: 4s;`
    `animation-timing-function: linear;`
    `animation-name:"rotate";`
    `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`
or for keyframe method?
how can i fix this?

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
0% {
    -webkit-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(0deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(0deg);
    background-color:#2187e7;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #2187e7 25%, #a0eaff); 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #2187e7 25%, #a0eaff); 
}  

  13% {
    -webkit-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(45deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  25% {
  -webkit-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(90deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-90deg);
  }
  38% {
  -webkit-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(135deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
  -webkit-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(180deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-180deg);
  }
  63% {
  -webkit-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(225deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(225deg);
  }
  75% {
  -webkit-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(270deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-270deg);
  }
  88% {
  -webkit-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(315deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(315deg);
  }
    100% {
    -webkit-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(360deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
/************** F I R E F O X ***********************/
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
0% {
    -moz-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(0deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(0deg);
    background-color:#2187e7;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #2187e7 25%, #a0eaff); 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #2187e7 25%, #a0eaff); 
}  

  13% {
    -moz-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(45deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-45deg);
   }
  25% {
  -moz-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(90deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-90deg);
  }
  38% {
  -moz-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(135deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
  -moz-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(180deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-180deg);
  }
  63% {
  -moz-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(225deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(225deg);
  }
  75% {
  -moz-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(270deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-270deg);
  }
  88% {
  -moz-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(315deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(315deg);
  }
    100% {
    -moz-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(360deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
/************************************/
@keyframes rotate {
    0% {
    transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(0deg) translate(-73px, -73px)     rotate(0deg);
    background-color:#2187e7;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #2187e7 25%, #a0eaff); 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #2187e7 25%, #a0eaff); 
    }  

  13% {
    transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(45deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-45deg);
   }
  25% {
  transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(90deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-90deg);
  }
  38% {
  transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(135deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
  transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(180deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-180deg);
  }
  63% {
  transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(225deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(225deg);
  }
  75% {
  transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(270deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-270deg);
  }
  88% {
  transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(315deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(315deg);
  }
        100% {
    transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(360deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-360deg);
        }
        }
    /************** I E ***********************/
@-ms-keyframes rotate {
    0% {
    -ms-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(0deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(0deg);
    background-color:#2187e7;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #2187e7 25%, #a0eaff); 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #2187e7 25%, #a0eaff); 
    }  

  13% {
    -ms-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(45deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-45deg);
   }
  25% {
  -ms-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(90deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-90deg);
  }
  38% {
  -ms-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(135deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
  -ms-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(180deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-180deg);
  }
  63% {
  -ms-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(225deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(225deg);
  }
  75% {
  -ms-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(270deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-270deg);
  }
  88% {
  -ms-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(315deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(315deg);
  }
    100% {
    -ms-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(360deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
/************************************/
@-o-keyframes rotate {
0% {
    -o-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(0deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(0deg);
    background-color:#2187e7;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #2187e7 25%, #a0eaff); 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #2187e7 25%, #a0eaff); 
    }  

  13% {
    -o-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(45deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-45deg);
   }
  25% {
  -o-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(90deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-90deg);
  }
  38% {
  -o-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(135deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
  -o-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(180deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-180deg);
  }
  63% {
  -o-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(225deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(225deg);
  }
  75% {
  -o-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(270deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-270deg);
  }
  88% {
  -o-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(315deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(315deg);
  }
    100% {
    -o-transform:translate(73px, 73px) rotate(360deg) translate(-73px, -73px) rotate(-360deg);
}
}

/*************************************/
#circle {
height: 10px;
width: 10px;
border-radius:25px;
background-color:#2187e7;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #2187e7 25%, #a0eaff); 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #2187e7 25%, #a0eaff);

-webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-name:"rotate";
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

animation-duration: 4s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-name:"rotate";
animation-iteration-count: infinite;

-moz-animation-duration: 4s;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
-moz-animation-name:"rotate";
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

-ms-animation-duration: 4s;
-ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
-ms-animation-name:"rotate";
-ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

-o-animation-duration: 4s;
-o-animation-timing-function: linear;
-o-animation-name:"rotate";
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

position:absolute;
left:-1%;
top:-1%; 
}
```

Comment: Don't set all this inside a -webkit-keyframes . Set prefixed keyframes with prefixed properties inside, and keyframes with unprefixed properties

Comment: i edit my code, please check, and it just work in chrome not in other browsers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the double quotes from the animation name (`rotate` instead of `"rotate"`).

Then it will work:

[Running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HACsC/)

```
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-name:rotate;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

-moz-animation-duration: 4s;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
-moz-animation-name:rotate;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

-ms-animation-duration: 4s;
-ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
-ms-animation-name:rotate;
-ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

-o-animation-duration: 4s;
-o-animation-timing-function: linear;
-o-animation-name:rotate;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

animation-duration: 4s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-name:rotate;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

Remember, the non-prefixed properties must always be the last, after the vendor specific.

P.S: In case you don't know, there are sites that prefix your code at compile-time (like [Prefixr](http://prefixr.com/)), or even at run-time (like [prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/)).

Btw +1, your animation is pretty :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x5x1ax4n/ Mine doesn't work in IE for some reason. Can you please help? I like the animation also. +1.

Comment: Which IE version ?